# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Tomcat Server HTML page Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: java, html, servlets

When I try to run my Tomcat server and input the bottom most, right most value in the Tic-Tac-Toe grid, I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    vejus.satya.tictactoe.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:33)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is my HTML code inside my form:

```
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="0"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="1"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="2"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="3"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="4"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="5"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="6"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="7"> </td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="input" value="8"> </td>
  </tr>
```

Here is my Java code that takes this:

```
String[] board = new String[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i ++) {
    board[i] = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"input\" value=\"" + i + "\">";
}

int loc = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("input"));
board[loc] = "X";
```

How do I fix this? The input I get is 9 while I made it 8 in the HTML code as you can see above, so I don't know **why my input value is not working**. This is why I get this error.

Comment: If you input 9 it is out of bounds.

Comment: have you tried re-deploying your project?

Comment: @emsimpson92 That isn't true. Size 9 means indices 0-8, which < accomplishes.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala If u mean restarting my server and trying multiple times, then yes.

Comment: @SatyaVejus No. Give it a clean and build

Comment: How is `req` constructed? You should show some more code.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala How do I do this? Can you give me some code?

Comment: @NiVeR `req` is the `HttpServletRequest` object.

Comment: @SatyaVejus what is the IDE which you are using? Netbeans?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I know what it is, I asked *how* is constructed, or in other words how parameter **input** is set.

Comment: @NiVeR it's done automatically by the web container. We cannot `setParameters()`

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Are you both working on the same project?

Comment: @NiVeR No. It's the default situation.

Comment: I'm currently reproducing his error

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala You are wrong. Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)

Comment: @NiVeR are you suggesting that there are more than 1 input parameters passed by the HTML form?

Comment: @SatyaVejus Are you using any kind of IDE to develop this?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Also that, but firstly that parameters can be set client-side.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Oxygen 3a. Also there is only 1 parameter from the HTML form: input, which has a number value as shown above.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to redeploy the web app using the Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1654631)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it works now. All I did was remove the project from the server and then add it again, and then run the server. Simple refresh resolution

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this error. In fact there is no possible error which can be identified from the code. Anyway, I can think of a single solution which may help you.

As you are coding in a servlet, make sure you re-deploy after your edits.

---

If you are using NetBeans,

> Window → Projects → Right Click on your project name → Click Deploy.

---

In Eclipse,

- Right-click the model in the Package Explorer view.
- Select Export....
- Choose Process Manager Wizards > Deploy Process Model.
- Click Next.
- In the Deploy wizard check that your process model is selected.
- Select Finish.

Comment: How do you deploy in Eclipse